# PHP: How to check if one datetime value lies outside of two other datetime values

Tags: php, datetime, if-statement

I'm working on a website that can show error notifications. These notifications are activated when the current date exists between a begin- and endtime, which is set in the database. Checking if the current date exists inbetween these two values is done in some places in my code using:

```
if($Notification['beginTime'] < $currentDate && $Notification['endTime'] > $currentDate){
        error_log("something went wrong");
    } else{
        updateInternalNotification();
    }
```

However, I now would like to switch the if statement around so that it checks if the current date lies outside of the begin- and endtime and thus the notification isn't active.

I have tried doing this:

```
    if($currentDate < $Notification['beginTime' && $currentDate > $Notification['endTime']){
        updateInternalNotification();  
      }
```

However, In my mind one dateTime value cannot lie outside of two other values. It does not make sense to me. Could any of you help me understand this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: The time will either be lower than the begin time, _or_ higher than the end time ... so switch the `&&` out for an `||` ...?

Comment: Also `$Notification['beginTime'` looks like a typo, should be `$Notification['beginTime']` surely?